# Scholarships and the PhD thesis in the Scandinavian system?

Tags: phd, thesis, funding, europe

I'm totally confused about how you have to write your desired thesis in the Scandinavian higher education system when you've got their scholarship. By reading the articles about how it works I feel that I have become more disoriented.

When you read promotions about hiring new Ph.D. students in the universities' websites or places such as Scholarshipdb.net it's often said that you have to do research on a particular field. Is this research counts as your dissertation or you have to do your own thesis aside from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have seen (a whole bunch of PhD students, though I have done my PhD elsewhere) is that the research PhD students do is going to be the content of the thesis. The thesis contains two parts, the manuscripts/articles published, and a coherent story based on the work.

So the thesis is a product of the research the students are doing during their PhD.

Now, this might be different for some fields, or funding situations, and quite likely, for industrial PhD positions.

Comment: Thank you. But what about when you have a genuine idea for your thesis that is so important for your field of study? Could you write that instead and get funded?

Comment: If you can find someone who gives you money, and someone else who wants to supervise you, sure.